# How do both clients know the private keys?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key, public-key-encryption, private-key

I understand that when sending a message, the message is encrypted with a public key and sent over, requiring a private key to open the encrypted message. However I wonder how both clients know the private keys. For example:

**John sends a message to Alice saying "Hello World".**

**The message get's encrypted with a public key, and sent**

**Alice decrypts it with a private key.**

But, how does Alice's computer know the private key, how does it get there, does it come with the encrypted message in another layer of encryption, or is it on both of the computer at the start, but how?

I am just wondering, and it would be great if anyone can please explain thanks!

Comment: Only one party needs the private key. It's the public key that needs to be distributed.

Answer (score 1):

Both parties generate their **own** private keys that stay with them.  The public portion of these keys are then distributed to other parties that want to communicate with the owner of the private key.

The important part is ensuring that you are communicating with who you think you are communicating with, otherwise the middle-man could send his public key to both parties masquerading as the intended recipient.

This answer does, to some degree, assume we are talking about RSA.  There are many asymmetric cryptosystems that use private/public keys that may not necessarily make sense with the terminology I've used.

Comment: Yes, but how does the other party knows what is the private key to unlock the decrypted message?

Comment: I don't understand what you aren't understanding.  I generate a private and public key and give my public key to you.  You encrypt a message and send the encrypted message to me.  I use my private key to decrypt it.  Voila.

Comment: Now I understand it, at first I thought that you generate and encrypt the message with a public key and then send it to me, and somehow I know the private key, and decrypt it. Thanks for clarifying the order for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest model:

- Alice generates a keypair `Apub` / `Apriv`.
- Bob doesn't need keys if this is RSA.
- Alice sends Apub to Bob.  She does this securely (exercise left to the reader).
- Bob encrypts some data using `Apub`.
- Bob sends his encrypted stuff to Alice.
- Alice knew *a priori* (simple scenario, remember?) which key was being used, and uses `Apriv` to recover the data.

In more complex models entities may have many private keys.  Aside from "try all of them" we can add some structure.

- Alice generates a keypair `Apub` / `Apriv`.  She saves these securely (exercise left to the reader).
- Alice obtains an X.509 Public Key Certificate with `Apub` as the subject public key.

  - Self signed is fine here, or CA-issued is always good.
- Bob still is a happy man who doesn't need to manage keys.  That makes his FISMA/PCI/etc compliance audits easier.
- Alice sends her certificate to Bob.  She does this securely (ELTTR).
- Bob (uses software which) extracts `Apub` from the certificate and encrypts data using it.
- Bob('s software) builds a formatted message which includes a way to identify which certificate was used, and what the encrypted content is.

  - Maybe he just sends the whole cert back. (Probably not)
  - Maybe he sends the certificate Issuer Name and Serial Number values.
  - Maybe he sends the Subject Key Identifier extension value from the cert.
  - He has lots of options, as long as Alice understands what he's doing.
- Bob sends this formatted message to Alice.
- Alice identifies which of her several certificates was addressed in the formatted message.
- Alice has a key management system and can figure out which private key to use based on the certificate.
- Alice uses `Apriv` to recover the data.

The more complex model is a simplistic form of Enveloped CMS (Cryptographic Message Syntax) on Bob's part.  Alice read the message and used something like the Windows Certificate Store (which is capable of carrying identifiers to Windows Cryptographic Key Stores for private keys) to determine the certificate and ultimately the private key.

Lots of different things could be done at the "more complex" layer.  If Alice really likes managing keys she could make a different key for each person she talks to, and then know from a messages "Bobness" or "Daviosity" that she should use the private key matching the public key she gave to Bob, or Dave.

Comment: One of the best and most detailed explanations so far, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

John uses Alice's public key to encrypt. Alice is the only one with the private key able to decrypt. Alice then responds, encrypting with John's public key, to which John decrypts using his private key.